# How to assign custom score in Atlas Search?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas-search

So, I am working on implementing autocomplete feature on MongoDB atlas search, and I have a field in my document which has the score of the particular search-keyword in the document.

Like, This is one of the field

```
Primary_Search   Hello
Relevant_Meaning Hi
Search_Score     10.66
```

and this is another

```
Primary_Search   Hi
Relevant_Meaning Hi
Search_Score     12.66
```

So both are different searches but have same relevant meaning so, in this case I will show the result with my Score-System which has higher Score.

P.S: I have indexed the collection with Primary_Search and Relevant Meaning as autocomplete type and Search_Score as Number type

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to obtain the same score for both results, but you have only indexed the `Primary_Search`? I would say that you can't do that, but I'm not sure. The thing is you obtain different score results because they're different strings. Anyway, take a look here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/scoring/ . Maybe you could apply some option in order to alter the final score. Good luck!

Comment: done the scoring using Function Scoring

Comment: and got the unique values through $group thanks!